# Changing size of floatingActionButton

Tags: flutter

I would like to change the size of a `FloatingActionButton`. However, the following is not accepting `height` and `width` values.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xff33333D),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Icon(Icons.camera),
),
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
```

How can I adjust to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FloatingActionButton sizes are defined in Material Design: https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button

You have two sizes: default and mini:

[image]

To define a mini FloatingActionButton, just add `mini: true`:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xff33333D),
  mini: true,
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Icon(Icons.camera),
),
```

Now, if you want another size, you could use an `ElevatedButton`:

[image]

```
floatingActionButton: ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 200, height: 200),
  child: ElevatedButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.camera, size: 160),
    onPressed: () {},
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      shape: CircleBorder(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 200, height: 200),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.camera, size: 160),
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 4.0,
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You will find other ways to define Circle Buttons here: https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-make-circular-buttons-in-flutter/

Comment: Thanks! But then there is a disconnect between the size of the icon, and the button itself, so when condensing to a smaller screen, would the icon not shift?

Comment: You have to properly define the size of your button and the size of your icon. How would you define the size of your FAB? In percentage of the screen size? Same for the icon, in percentage of the FAB?